# How to design printing bill format

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I am developing a project for small shop. I have done few modules, now i have to provide bill printing feature. how to design the bill format? (what are the available tools?)

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look to [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) (a reporting library) and [iReport Designer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) (a report designer with a good GUI).

Search Google for invoice templates with Jasper Reports, for example: http://help.wavelet.biz/getting-started/customize

Answer (score 2):

You can use this ready made [The HTML5 Invoice](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/the-html5-invoice/) from the site http://jonathantneal.com. You can see [demo here](http://www.jonathantneal.com/examples/invoice/)